# Login With Facebook Selenium script python

Tags: python, selenium

So I have been trying to create a selenium script that helps me Log in with facebook for spotify online. The page looks as follows.
[image: The image looks as follows]

The login link is within 2 divs. I have tried to fetch these by class names or the text in them which says "Log in with Facebook" But it does not help and gives me an error saying

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Log in with Facebook"}
```

How do I select the login with facebook button and click on it?

Answer (score 0):

Link text is in all uppercase:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK').click()
```

You can also use `class` instead, which is a better selector than link text. Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-facebook').click()
```

Comment: I get the following errors while using the 2 methods

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK"}

AND 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn-facebook"}

Comment: May be you need to wait for the page to load.

Comment: This helped. Thank you so much